# show error osgix:cm-properties when run the project

Tags: maven, apache-camel

I have xml configuration in my project, what means the code below? because when I run with mvn camel:run. the error show in line 21, in osgix:cm-properties, persistent-id tag. what means the code for? thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Configures the Camel Context -->

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ctx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf" xmlns:camel="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/camel"
    xmlns:osgi="http://camel.apache.org/schema/osgi" xmlns:osgix="http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi-compendium"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi/spring-osgi-1.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi-compendium http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi-compendium/spring-osgi-compendium-1.2.xsd
        http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/transports/camel http://cxf.apache.org/transports/camel.xsd
        http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf/camel-cxf.xsd
       ">

    <!-- FOR READ OSGI CONFIGURATION -->
    <osgix:cm-properties
        id="com.prudential.integration.middleware.crm.services"
        persistent-id="com.prudential.integration.middleware.crm.services" />

    <ctx:property-placeholder
        properties-ref="com.prudential.integration.middleware.crm.services" />
    <!-- FOR READ OSGI CONFIGURATION -->

    <bean id="crmProcess" class="com.prudential.integration.middleware.crm.services.process.CRMProcess">
        <property name="urlNewEmail" value="${urlNewEmail}" />
        <property name="reportLoc" value="${reportLoc}" />
        <property name="prefixReportName" value="${prefixReportName}" />
        <property name="csvDelimiter" value="${csvDelimiter}" />
        <property name="crmRequestTimeOut" value="${crmRequestTimeOut}" />
        <property name="crmReadTimeOut" value="${crmReadTimeOut}" />
    </bean>

    <cxf:rsServer id="crmEndPoint" address="/crm"
        serviceClass="com.prudential.integration.middleware.crm.services.service.CRMServices" />

</beans>
```

Comment: Are you asking what `osgix:cm-properties` means? If so its OSGi configuration management that are loaded via properties files. This code is using Spring-DM which is a dead project. It would be better to migrate to OSGi Blueprint XML format.

Comment: is there a wrong code in this xml? because when I run the project with mvn camel:run this show error in that line..

Comment: Post the error and tell us what version of Camel you are using.

Comment: And mind that mvn camel:run is not intended for running in production, certainly not OSGi which you need to run and deploy in an OSGi container such as Apache Karaf / ServiceMix etc. The mvn camel:run is not developers to quickly run Camel and "play with it"